# How to profile C++ code with Intel Parallel Studio XE?

Tags: c++, profiling, intel-parallel-studio

I am newbie using Intel Parallel Studio XE. I have already use profiling tools for Java. I just need to use Yourkit with an open port to listen a port from the Eclipse IDE. But with Intel Parallel Studio XE I don't know how to work and the manual doesn't help very much.

I have downloaded the student version to try to learn and implement some code in C++ and debug/profile it. I installed the Intel Parallel Studio and I execute the command line `source psxevars.sh`, but the only output that I can see is:

```
Intel(R) Parallel Studio XE 2018 Update 2 for Linux*
Copyright (C) 2009-2018 Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

How am I going to do profiling in some of my C++ programs? I was expecting to have an IDE to see the threads and processes.

Additionally, which IDE to develop C++ code is better integrated to the Intel Parallel Studio XE?

Kind Regards,
Felipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. I is on the folder: "/opt/intel/vtune_amplifier_2018",  `./bin64/amplxe-gui`